# how to calculate the performance using RMSE

Tags: r, imputation

How do i calculate RMSE between true and imputed values of Iris dataset.

I am generating 10% NA values in iris dataset.
Later i am imputing and predicting those values using Amelia package.

Now i need to caculate RMSE between original iris datset and the simulated iris dataset

Here is my code :

```
library(Amelia)

#load data
data("iris")

#produce 10% missing data 
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)
#summary(iris.mis)

#run amelia
#m  – Refers to 2 imputed data sets
#noms – keep nominal variables here

amelia_imp <- amelia(iris.mis, m=2, noms = "Species")

#check imputed outputs
amelia_imp$imputations[[1]]
amelia_imp$imputations[[2]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: rmse is probably not the right error function if you impute classes: `rmse <- function(x, y) sqrt(mean((x-y)^2)))`

Comment: i got the output.

Comment: Also, here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Metrics/versions/0.1.2/topics/rmse function already exists.